# inconsistent parentheses size when using Asana Math

Tags: fonts, typography, asana

I use `\setmathfont{Asana Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]` and use lualatex.

I noticed when I do this, I get different size of () depending if there is an extra term present or not around it.

Here is a MWE. This is using TL 2020 with latest update (after oct 1)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}  
\mleftright

\usepackage[mathit=sym,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\begin{document}

\[
 -\cos \left(x \right) {\mathrm e}^{x}+\cos \left(y \right)
\]
  
\end{document}
```

Compiled

```
lualatex foo5.tex
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./foo5.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2
    
 L3 programming layer <2020-10-27> xparse <2020-03-03> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/mleftright/mleftright.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-luatex.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-generic.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg))) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/lualatex-math/lualatex-math.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.tex))) (./foo5.aux) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./foo5.aux))
 488 words of node memory still in use:
   6 hlist, 2 vlist, 2 rule, 2 glue, 4 kern, 1 glyph, 7 attribute, 52 glue_spec, 7 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:39,3:21,4:4,5:23,6:2,7:72,8:23,9:42
</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/Asana-Math/Asana-Math.otf></usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf></usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/Asana-Math/Asana-Math.otf>
Output written on foo5.pdf (1 page, 6484 bytes).
Transcript written on foo5.log.
```

Gives

[image]

The parentheses around the second `cos` is much larger than the first and does not look nice. Removing the lines

```
\usepackage[mathit=sym,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
```

And compiling again gives

[image]

now parentheses are the same size as expected.  Please do not complain why I am using `\left` and `\right`, this is CAS auto-generated Latex and the above is small example from some of the latex generated. I have no control over that.

In my actual code, I am also using `Baskervaldx` with `Asana Math` but by testing, I found that only using `Asana Math` by itself shows this problem. So I tried to make the top MWE simpler to show the problem. But if you like to see the full font I am using, here is the MWE again. Same output is given as the first one above

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}  
\mleftright

\usepackage[mathit=sym,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmainfont{Baskervaldx}[
  UprightFont=*-Reg,
  ItalicFont=*-Ita,
  BoldFont=*-Bol,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BolIta,
]

\begin{document}

\[
 -\cos \left(x \right) {\mathrm e}^{x}+\cos \left(y \right)
\]   
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to use `Asana Math` and have parentheses size be the same. Again, I can't remove the `\left` and `\right` from the code.  Is there something I am doing wrong?

Any suggestions are welcome.

**edit  1/13/2021**

This is an example which produces an error using the lua code in the accepted answer. I do not know now why that is. This is autogenerated latex

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}  
\mleftright

\usepackage[mathit=sym,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

{\catcode`\%=12
\directlua{
function spuriousleftright(s)
 return string.gsub(s,'\string\\left(..[ ]*)\string\\right(.)','%1%2')
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback('process_input_buffer',spuriousleftright,'zzz')
}
}
\begin{document}

\[
y = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}\left[\right] & c_{2}+\frac{\ln \left(\frac{3 v \left(y \right)}{y}\right)}{2}<0 \\\left[0\right] & c_{2}+\frac{\ln \left(\frac{3 v \left(y \right)}{y}\right)}{2}=0 \\\left[c_{2}+\frac{\ln \left(\frac{3 v \left(y \right)}{y}\right)}{2}, -c_{2}-\frac{\ln \left(\frac{3 v \left(y \right)}{y}\right)}{2}\right] & 0<c_{2}+\frac{\ln \left(\frac{3 v \left(y \right)}{y}\right)}{2} \end{array}\right.
\]    
  
\end{document}
```

Now compiled using lualatex gives `! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).` error.

```
lualatex foo5.tex
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./foo5.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2


 L3 programming layer <2020-12-07> xparse <2020-03-03> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/mleftright/mleftright.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-luatex.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-generic.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg))) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/lualatex-math/lualatex-math.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.tex))) (./foo5.aux)
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
>
l.21 y = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}\left[\right] & c_{2}+\frac{\ln \left(\frac{3 v (y )}{y}\right)}{2}<0 \\[0]
                                                                                                           & c_{2}+\frac{\ln \left(\frac{3 v (y )}{y}\right)}{2}=0 \\\left[c_{2}+\frac{\ln \left(\frac{3 v (y )}{y}\right)}{2}, -c_{2}-\frac{\ln \left(\fra...
?
```

**edit  3/31/2021**

I found a case where the () remains large and not reduced like with other math functions. Here is a MWE. It is when using `\psi`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}  
\mleftright

\usepackage[mathit=sym,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

{\catcode`\%=12
\directlua{
function spuriousleftright(s)
 return string.gsub(s,'\string\\left(..[ ]*)\string\\right(.)','\string\\relax %1%2')
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback('process_input_buffer',spuriousleftright,'zzz')
}
}

\begin{document}

\[
 -\cos \left(x \right) +\cos \left(y \right)
\]

\[
 -\cos \left(x \right) +\psi\left(  y\right) 
\]       
\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare to when not using this font again:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}  
\mleftright

\begin{document}

\[
 -\cos \left(x \right) +\cos \left(y \right)
\]

\[
 -\cos \left(x \right) +\psi\left(  y\right) 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this must be the 1000th question you have asked caused by issues with `\left\right` you _can_ modify the output of CAS not to use `\left`right` so often (or you could simply post process the generated file with a regex to remove most of them, or you could define \left so that it does nothing if just surrounding a single letter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would fix the tex generation either within the CAS or by processing the generated tex before passing it to latex. Since you are using luatex you could do that processing on the fly but it is easier to debug if you do it externally where you can look at the transformed result, however this is modifying the input buffer on the fly via the callback

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}  
\mleftright

\usepackage[mathit=sym,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

{\catcode`\%=12
\directlua{
function spuriousleftright(s)
 return string.gsub(s,'\string\\left(..[ ]*)\string\\right(.)','\string\\relax %1%2')
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback('process_input_buffer',spuriousleftright,'zzz')
}
}
\begin{document}

\[
 -\cos \left(x \right) {\mathrm e}^{x}+\cos \left(y \right)
\]
  
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've been using the above, with no problems. Now I found some math which produces an error when using your lua fix. This is generated latex.  If I remove the lua code, it compiles ok. I'll post the example in my answer above in case you like to look at it.  This is the first time I found something which make you lua fix not work.

Comment: @Nasser If this is generated latex then fix the generator. It can't include `\left`, `right` at every occurences of `()`. The fix at lua level is only a wasteful fix which can bring more problems.

Comment: I have to agree with @wipet but anyway I stuck in an extra `\relax` to guard the `[` that may appear in the replacement text. Your example works now.

Comment: Thanks David. With your new lua version, the compile error went away. This is auto-generated Latex code, so I have little control on what it generates.

Comment: @Nasser you are running the generation so you have _complete_  control over the latex you generate. There really is no need to generate this.

Comment: Hello David. I've been using the above code of yours and its been working well. But now I  found a case where () remain large. This happens with \psi for example. I wonder why that is and if there is possibly an easy fix for it. I am posting a MWE now.

Comment: I found the cause. It is due to having space after the first `(`. So this `\psi\left(y\right) ` works OK, and () have the smaller size. But `\psi\left( y\right) ` keeps the () size large. So I think it just needs trimming the space between the `()` to fix it? It is strange that only with `\psi` this seems to cause this problem.

Comment: @Nasser it really makes no sense to still be using this months later. As a one off quick fix for a single document it might possibly have a justification but as both I and wipet said at the time, it is completely the wrong thing to be doing. You should fix your generator.

Comment: David. Your code works well. But the issue is when there is space after first `(`. For example  `\psi\left( y\right)`  Just need a way to strip white space there.  This is latex generated by Scientific workplace V 5.5. So when you say to fix generator,  I do not understand. This is how SW generates the Latex. I use SW to write my HW and then compile the latex.  I am not good in lua programming, but will try to see if there is a way to strip the space there and may be figure how to change your code.  Best.

Comment: @Nasser most likely you just want to add `[ ]*` befioe the `..` but really you shouldn't be doing this at all

Answer (score 3):

A minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\begin{document}

$\left(x\right)\left(y\right)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The glyph for `y` has a very deep descender and TeX follows the rules for `\left` and `\right`.

You can avoid the issue by smashing the descender (not the best solution, but your typesetting is not the highest quality anyway).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\Umathcharnumdef\standardy=\Umathcodenum`y
\begingroup\lccode`~=`y \lowercase{\endgroup
  \AtBeginDocument{\def~{{\smash[b]{\standardy}}}\mathcode`y="8000 }
}

\begin{document}

$\left(x\right)\left(y\right)\left(p\right)\left(b\right)$

\textit{xypb}

\end{document}
```

As you see, though, also other letters need the same treatment. And I added the italic letters in Baskervaldx to show what I mean “not the highest quality”.

[image]